# How to set all elements inside a column to be the same height as the row but not lose margin?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

This question doesn't ask how to make the columns the same height, but how to make the contents fill the height of the columns.

I have a row with two cards. While the columns are the same height, the cards are not.

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| +-----------------------+ | +-----------------------+ |
| |                       | | |                       | |
| |                       | | |                       | |
| |                       | | |                       | |
| +-----------------------+ | |                       | |
|                           | |                       | |
|                           | |                       | |
|                           | |                       | |
|                           | +-----------------------+ |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

I have added the class `.h-100` to the first card, but that makes that card lose its bottom margin, so it doesn't line up with the other one. If I add `h-100` to both, the cards are the same heights, but I lose the bottom margin on both. Is there a correct way to have the cards full height in each column?

https://jsfiddle.net/yjfzvpoh/1/

Please see this snippet:

```html
<style>
.card {
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
width: 100%;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card h-100">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="personal-information mt-30">
            <div class="name-text">
              <h6 class="font-14"><span class="text-muted">Trabajador :</span> Ninguno asociado</h6>
              <h6 class="font-14"><span class="text-muted">E-mail :</span> jstuardo@desytec.com</h6>
              <h6 class="font-14"><span class="text-muted">Teléfono :</span> </h6>
              <h6 class="font-14"><span class="text-muted">Cliente :</span> Ninguno asignado</h6>
              <h6 class="font-14"><span class="text-muted">Empresas :</span> Ninguna asignada</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Cambio de contraseña</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col">
            <h6 class="font-14 mb-0">
              <i class="fa fa-user-o me-2 text-info"></i>Nombre de usuario
            </h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <span class="font-14">jstuardo</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form action="/Account/Manage" autocomplete="off" class="needs-validation pwd-form" id="frmChange" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" role="form"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="YoNbftpwnbNFettprMIOSZgRixGJkdGWjWERzrXeZYESy0sKEYkLxphjFXtG3H7Nz0PKmU91hgGUGbgBuXhY4kc3yyx7-27oWj2IgVEEkwbutZEaWYP-PVyiYgrRx5-Pvhk1n6cq6lewMmrwtthNJA2">
          <hr class="my-3">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
              <h6 class="font-14 mb-0">
                <i class="fa fa-key me-2 text-success"></i>Contraseña actual
              </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input name="OldPassword" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="La Contraseña debe tener al menos 6 caracteres." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length-min="6" id="OldPassword" maxlength="50" required="required"
                  type="password">
                <span toggle="#OldPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                  Ingrese la contraseña actual.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="my-3">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
              <h6 class="font-14 mb-0">
                <i class="fa fa-key me-2 text-danger"></i>Nueva contraseña
              </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input name="NewPassword" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" id="NewPassword" maxlength="50" required="required" type="password">
                <span toggle="#NewPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                  Ingrese la nueva contraseña.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="my-3">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
              <h6 class="font-14 mb-0">
                <i class="fa fa-key me-2 text-primary"></i>Confirmación de contraseña
              </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="La contraseña y su confirmación no coinciden." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ConfirmPassword" maxlength="50" name="ConfirmPassword" required="required"
                  type="password">
                <span toggle="#ConfirmPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                  Confirmación incorrecta.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <hr class="my-3">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col"></div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <span class="font-14"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnCambiar"><i class="fa fa-key me-2"></i>Cambiar contraseña</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
This is another card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to set the left `div` to be the same height of the right `div`? I need, in fact, both `div` has the same inner height of the `div` whose class is `row`

Comment: `<div class="card h-100">`

Comment: @Popnoodles I have tried it, but the problem is that I have a bottom margin of the card. When using `h-100`, that margin disappears. Please see the edited snippet. That includes a `card` class definition belonging to the template I am using in this site.

Comment: Hang on, you're adding margin to the card, and the rows by default have no margin, so add the margin to the row instead.

Comment: **This is not a duplicate of the other question** as it pertains to cells INSIDE the columns. The other question answers how to make the columns the same height, not their contents. I created the accepted answer the linked question and it does not answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I can only find a hack to solve this, and that's to add a wrapper to each card, use padding on that as the margin, and have all the cards 100% height.

I've changed the cols to `col-6` from `col-md-6` so they show in this snippet.

https://jsfiddle.net/yt0e5nxb/

```html
<style>
.card-wrapper{
padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
height: 100%;
}
.card {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="personal-information mt-30">
            <div class="name-text">
              <h6 class="font-14"><span class="text-muted">Trabajador :</span> Ninguno asociado</h6>
              <h6 class="font-14"><span class="text-muted">E-mail :</span> jstuardo@desytec.com</h6>
              <h6 class="font-14"><span class="text-muted">Teléfono :</span> </h6>
              <h6 class="font-14"><span class="text-muted">Cliente :</span> Ninguno asignado</h6>
              <h6 class="font-14"><span class="text-muted">Empresas :</span> Ninguna asignada</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Cambio de contraseña</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col">
            <h6 class="font-14 mb-0">
              <i class="fa fa-user-o me-2 text-info"></i>Nombre de usuario
            </h6>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <span class="font-14">jstuardo</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <form action="/Account/Manage" autocomplete="off" class="needs-validation pwd-form" id="frmChange" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" role="form"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="YoNbftpwnbNFettprMIOSZgRixGJkdGWjWERzrXeZYESy0sKEYkLxphjFXtG3H7Nz0PKmU91hgGUGbgBuXhY4kc3yyx7-27oWj2IgVEEkwbutZEaWYP-PVyiYgrRx5-Pvhk1n6cq6lewMmrwtthNJA2">
          <hr class="my-3">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
              <h6 class="font-14 mb-0">
                <i class="fa fa-key me-2 text-success"></i>Contraseña actual
              </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input name="OldPassword" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="La Contraseña debe tener al menos 6 caracteres." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length-min="6" id="OldPassword" maxlength="50" required="required"
                  type="password">
                <span toggle="#OldPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                  Ingrese la contraseña actual.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="my-3">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
              <h6 class="font-14 mb-0">
                <i class="fa fa-key me-2 text-danger"></i>Nueva contraseña
              </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input name="NewPassword" autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" id="NewPassword" maxlength="50" required="required" type="password">
                <span toggle="#NewPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                  Ingrese la nueva contraseña.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="my-3">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col">
              <h6 class="font-14 mb-0">
                <i class="fa fa-key me-2 text-primary"></i>Confirmación de contraseña
              </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input autocomplete="new-password" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-equalto="La contraseña y su confirmación no coinciden." data-val-equalto-other="*.Password" id="ConfirmPassword" maxlength="50" name="ConfirmPassword" required="required"
                  type="password">
                <span toggle="#ConfirmPassword" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash field-icon toggle-password"></span>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                  Confirmación incorrecta.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
        <hr class="my-3">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col"></div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <span class="font-14"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnCambiar"><i class="fa fa-key me-2"></i>Cambiar contraseña</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
This is another card
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```